# activeadmin sortable works with sqlite but not postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using activeadmin.  I am trying to make an activeadmin page for a person.  A person `belongs_to :team` and a team `has_many :people`.  In development with sqlite, the following code works perfectly:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Person, as: "vc" do
    index do
        column :team, sortable: :team
    end
    def scoped_collection
        p = Person.with_any_role(*Person.value_consumer_role_names).collect(&:id)
        Person.includes(:team).where(id: p)
    end
end
```

However, in production using Heroku and Postgresql, I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "team" does not exist
```

How do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In the column line, you need to reference the teams table, not model:

```
column :team, sortable: 'teams.name'
```